# Symfony валидация

Tags: symfony, валидация

Всем привет, возможно кто-то сталкивался с ситуацией когда надо валидировать одно поле и в зависимости от типа юзера валидация нужна или нет.

В моем случаи есть обьект User у него есть поле "name" и поле "type" , поле "type" может natural, juridical  так вот мне надо сделать чтобы для natural на поле name валидация не работала а для юридического работала как

```
 * @UniqueEntity("name")
```

как это можно сделать?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте ValidationGroups.
Ваш класс:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;

/**
 * Class MyClass
 * @package AppBundle\Entity
 * @UniqueEntity(fields={"name"},groups={"juridical"})
 */
class MyClass
{
    /**
     *  типа enum
     */
    const TYPE_NATURAL = 'natural';
    const TYPE_JURIDICAL = 'juridical';

    /**
     * @var string Имя
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @var string Тип
     */
    private $type;

    .......

}
```

Ваша форма:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use AppBundle\Entity\MyClass;

class MyClassType extends AbstractType
{


    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('name', TextType::class);
        //что-то еще
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolver $resolver
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'validation_groups' => function (FormInterface $form) {
                $data = $form->getData();

                if (MyClass::TYPE_NATURAL === $data->getType()) {
                    return ['Default','juridical'];
                }

                return ['Default', 'natural'];
            },
        ]);
    }

}
```